# using tidygraph to merge two edges from the same two nodes into one

Tags: r, igraph, visnetwork, tidygraph

I'm struggling to figure out how to collapse 2 edges between the same 2 nodes into 1 and then calculate the sum of these edges.

I believe there's a way of doing it in `igraph`:

`simplify(gcon, edge.attr.comb = list(weight = "sum", function(x)length(x)))`

but I'd like to do it with `tidygraph` if possible as I've had success in implementing up to this point with `tidygraph` and I'm much more familiar with the `tidyverse` way of working.

My data looks like this:

```
  from to Strength Dataframe Question                Topic
1    0 32        4    weekly        1 Connection Frequency
2    0 19        5    weekly        1 Connection Frequency
3    0  8        3    weekly        1 Connection Frequency
4    0  6        5    weekly        1 Connection Frequency
5    0  2        4    weekly        1 Connection Frequency
6    0 14        5    weekly        1 Connection Frequency
```

With both 'from' and 'to' containing the same id's (e.g. from-to; 0-1 & 1-0). I'd like to condense so that only one iteration of the 0-1 relationship exists, with a summed `Strength` calculated.

Here's my code thus far:

```
graph <- data %>%
  filter(Dataframe == "weekly" & Question == 1) %>%
  as_tbl_graph(directed = FALSE) %>%
  activate(edges) %>% # first manipulate edges
  filter(!edge_is_loop()) %>% # remove any loops
  activate(nodes) %>% # now manipulate nodes
  left_join(node.group, by = "name") %>% 
  mutate(
    Popularity = centrality_degree(mode = 'in'),
    Centre = node_is_center(),
    Keyplayer = node_is_keyplayer(k = 5))
```

Is it possible to merge the two corresponding edges into a single edge? I've searched the forum but have only come across references where the same nodes are repeated in the same columns (i.e. 0-1's across multiple rows).

Comment: please include your expected output data.frame as well.

Comment: Seems kind of clunky, but I'd remove the second instance of each pair, switch the order, bind it back, and then summarize.  I'd do it in answer below if you post some data to recreate it.  Check out this post for posting great questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're out of luck for a pure `tidygraph` solution. `tidygraph::to_simple()` sets `igraph::simplify()`'s `edge.attr.comb` argument for you (`list`). You can use `convert(to_simple)` and then `map()` over the nested attributes, but then you're making more trouble for yourself than just using `igraph` and converting the result back to a `tbl_g`.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help. As per suggestions I have given up on utilising tidygraph and have achieved it through igraph instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidygraph) # v1.2.0
library(dplyr) # v0.8.5
library(purrr) # v0.3.4

dat <- data.frame(
  from = c("a", "a", "b", "c"),
  to = c("b", "b", "a", "b"),
  n = 1:4
)
```

Call `to_simple()` within `convert()` to collapse parallel edges. The corresponding edges and weights are stored in `.orig_data` as a list of tibbles. Then, extract the sum of the weight of collapsed edges from `.orig_data`.

```
dat %>% 
  as_tbl_graph() %>% 
  convert(to_simple) %>% 
  activate(edges) %>% 
  mutate(n_sum = map_dbl(.orig_data, ~ sum(.x$n)))

# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 3 edges
#
# A directed simple graph with 1 component
#
# Edge Data: 3 x 5 (active)
   from    to .tidygraph_edge_index .orig_data       n_sum
  <int> <int> <list>                <list>           <dbl>
1     1     2 <int [2]>             <tibble [2 x 3]>     3
2     2     1 <int [1]>             <tibble [1 x 3]>     3
3     3     2 <int [1]>             <tibble [1 x 3]>     4
#
# Node Data: 3 x 2
  name  .tidygraph_node_index
  <chr>                 <int>
1 a                         1
2 b                         2
3 c                         3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse multiple edges in a graph g by jumping to a weighted adjacency metrix and back into an igraph graph like this:

```
gg <- graph.adjacency(get.adjacency(g), mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)
```

Now `gg` will contain the edge-attribute `$weight` corresponding to the number of edges that occurred between each vertex-pair in `g`.

I'm not so familiar with tidygraph, but I made this pedagogical code to ease your path.

```
# A graph from sample data
sample_el <- cbind(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8),
                   c(2,2,3,6,6,4,4,6,8,5,5,6,8,7,7,2,6,8,3,6,4,4))
g <- graph_from_edgelist(sample_el, directed=F)

# Always plot graphs with this same layout
mylaoyt <- layout_(g, as_star())
plot(g, layout = mylaoyt)

# Merge all duplicate edges using a weighted adjacency matric that
# is converted back to a graph
gg <- graph.adjacency(get.adjacency(g), mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)

# function to return a weighted edgelist from a graph
get.weighted.edgelist <- function(graph){cbind(get.edgelist(gg), E(gg)$weight)}

# compare your two edge-lists. el has duplicates, wel is weighted
el <- get.edgelist(g)
wel<- get.weighted.edgelist(gg)
el
wel

# Plot the two graphs to see what el and wel would look like:
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(g, layout=mylaoyt, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=10)
plot(gg, layout=mylaoyt, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=10, edge.width=E(gg)$weight * 3)
```

The output in `el` and `wel` is visualise like so:

[image: Example graph with multiple and merged, weighted edges respectively]

Hope that you can carve out what you'll need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling on this problem, too.
My solution so far is to collapse pairs of each nodes then sum the weights up.
Something like this:

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

pasteCols = function(x, y, sep = ":"){
  stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))
  return(lapply(1:length(x), function(i){paste0(sort(c(x[i], y[i])), collapse = ":")}) %>% unlist())
}
data = data %>% 
  mutate(col_pairs = pasteCols(from, to, sep = ":")) %>% 
  group_by(col_pairs) %>% summarise(sum_weight = sum(weight)) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(col = col_pairs, c("from", "to"), sep = ":")
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me so, thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

`tidygraph` can simplify graphs when in a `morph`ed state with the `simplify_to` call, but it reverts to the original when `unmorph`ing.

This is a tidy workaround:

```
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
from to weight
0 14 5 
0  1 1 
1  0 1
")

original <- as_tbl_graph(data)
```

Input:

```
> original
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 3 edges
#
# A directed simple graph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 3 x 1 (active)
  name 
  <chr>
1 0    
2 1    
3 14   
#
# Edge Data: 3 x 3
   from    to weight
  <int> <int>    <int>
1     1     3        5
2     1     2        1
3     2     1        1
```

Solution:

```
modified <- original %>% activate(edges) %>% 
    # create a temporary grouping & filtering variable by sorting from/to IDs
    mutate(temp = ifelse(from > to, paste0(to, from), paste0(from, to))) %>% 
    group_by(temp) %>% 
    mutate(weight = sum(weight)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    dplyr::distinct(temp, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    select(-temp)
```

Output:

```
> modified   
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Edge Data: 2 x 3 (active)
   from    to weight
  <int> <int>    <int>
1     1     3        5
2     1     2        2
#
# Node Data: 3 x 1
  name 
  <chr>
1 0    
2 1    
3 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach. It uses `tidygraph`, which uses `igraph` under the hood.

```r
library(tidygraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidygraph':
#> 
#>     groups
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union
library(ggraph)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(tidyverse)


g <- tibble(from = sample(letters[1:5], 25, T), 
       to = sample(letters[1:5], 25, T)) %>% 
  as_tbl_graph()



ggraph(g)+
  geom_edge_parallel(arrow = arrow(type = 'closed'), 
                     start_cap = circle(7.5, 'mm'), 
                     end_cap = circle(7.5, 'mm'))+
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name))+
  labs(title = 'Multiple edges shown between node pairs')
#> Using `stress` as default layout
```

[image]

```r
# Add the weigths as counts in the original dataframe

g_weights <- g %>% 
  activate(edges) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(link = glue::glue('{from}_{to}')) %>% 
  add_count(link) %>% 
  distinct(link, n, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  select(from, to, n) %>% 
  as_tbl_graph()

ggraph(g_weights)+
  geom_edge_parallel(arrow = arrow(type = 'closed'), 
           start_cap = circle(7.5, 'mm'), 
           end_cap = circle(7.5, 'mm'), 
           aes(width = n))+
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name))+
  labs(title = 'Single edges shown between node pairs', 
       subtitle = 'Weights used as edge width')+
  scale_edge_width(range = c(.5, 2), name = 'Weight')
#> Using `stress` as default layout
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>